# How to find all squares of a certain size inside a circle grid

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw various non overlaping squares in a circle area in a canvas.

Originaly I tried to create squares at random positions inside the circle and check if they overlaped or not,but after sometime i realized it was too inefficient and too complicated for what i needed.

I want an algotithm that use the center of the circle coordenates,the radius of the circle, and the size of the square grid and returns an array of coordenates for the positions of each square on the grid that has all of its edges inside the cirle.

Comment: Please provide some form of partial implementation? Help us help you! :) **Edit:-** There's many ways in which you could achieve this.

Comment: By "_get all squares_" do you mean it should find the maximum number of grid squares in the circle with the given size? Please provide the input format and precise problem definition and desired output, if you consider this an algorithm problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want there to be unfilled space in the circle rather than filling it with partial squares? If so, valid squares will be those with all four corners inside the circle, so a simple loop will find them for you. The code below should do it, though you may want to condense it more as I've split it up for clarity.

```
const size = 4; // The size of each square.
const squareCoords = []; // The top-left corners of each valid square.
const circle = [10, 10, 10]; // The circle, in the form [centerX, centerY, radius]

function DistanceSquared(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return (x2-x1) ** 2 + (y2-y1) ** 2;
}
function isInsideCircle(x, y, cx, cy, r) {
    return (DistanceSquared(x, y, cx, cy) <= r ** 2);
}

let topLeftInside = false, bottomRightInside = false, topRightInside = false, bottomLeftInside = false;
for (let xx = circle[0] - circle[2]; xx < circle[0] + circle[2]; xx += size) {
    for (let yy = circle[1] - circle[2]; yy < circle[1] + circle[2]; yy += size) {
        topLeftInside = isInsideCircle(xx, yy, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2]);
        bottomRightInside = isInsideCircle(xx + size, yy + size, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2]);
        bottomLeftInside = isInsideCircle(xx, yy + size, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2]);
        topRightInside = isInsideCircle(xx + size, yy, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2]);
        if (topLeftInside && bottomRightInside && bottomLeftInside && topRightInside) {
            squareCoords.push([xx, yy]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code finds 0 squares with side 2 in the circle [2, 2, 2].

Comment: @jal_a Hm. The other option is to check every pixel and only jump ahead `size` pixels when there's a match, but that seems inefficient. Perhaps my entire approach isn't the best?

Comment: The question is not clearly defined. Your approach puts the circle and the squares in predefined coordinates and that limits the number of matching squares. Though it might work for the OP but if the algorithm needs the maximum number of squares then it needs a different approach.

Comment: "I want an algotithm that use the center of the circle coordenates,the radius of the circle, and the size of the square grid and returns an array of coordenates for the positions of each square on the grid that is inside the cirle." Sounds to me like he wants the coordinates of the squares, not the maximum number; and given a grid of a specified size would limit those squares to only one possible covering set.

Comment: It would be good to add a pre-filter to identify those squares which fit in the largest inscribed square within the circle. This could accelerate operations by reducing the amount of mathematics necessary.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Yeah the output needs to be coordinates but as I pointed out in a circle (2, 2) r=2 fits the square with top left (1, 1) and side=2 and that's just one example that changes the number of matching squares. So the algorithm can take that into account and find more matching squares. But anyway it depends on problem definition if it needs "all the squares" that can fit in the circle.